Algorithm for A071585 and other conjectures

Let $a(n)$ be A071585 (i.e., numerator of the continued fraction expansion whose terms are the first-order differences of exponents in the binary representation of $4n$, with the exponents of $2$ being listed in descending order). Here
$$
a(2^k + 2^j + m) = (k-j)a(2^j + m) + a(m), \\
a(0) = 1.
$$
for $2^k > 2^j > m \geqslant 0$.
Let $\ell(n)$ be the length of the binary expansion of $n$ minus $1$. Here
$$
\ell(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor.
$$
Let $T(n,k)$ be the $(k+1)$-th bit from the right side in the binary expansion of $n$. Here
$$
T(n,k) = \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\bmod 2.
$$
Let $b(n)$ be an integer sequence such that $b(n)=A$ after the whole transfrom where we start with $A:=1, B:=0, C:=-1$ and for $i$ from $0$ to $\ell(n)$ apply $C:=C+1, B:=B+(-1)^C A$ if $T(n,\ell(n)-i)=1$ and also apply $A:=A+(-1)^C B$ (at each step of the cycle).
Let $c(n)$ be an integer sequence such that $c(n)=A$ after the whole transfrom where we start with $A:=1, B:=0, C:=-1$ and for $i$ from $0$ to $\ell(n)$ apply $C:=C+1, B:=B+(-1)^C 2^{\ell(n)-i} A$ if $T(n,\ell(n)-i)=1$ and also apply $A:=A+(-1)^C B$ (at each step of the cycle).
Let $d(n)$ be an integer sequence such that $d(n)=A$ after the whole transfrom where we start with $A:=1, B:=0, C:=-1$ and for $i$ from $0$ to $\ell(n)$ apply $C:=C+1, B:=B+(-1)^C A$ if $T(n,\ell(n)-i)=1$ and also apply $A:=A+(-1)^C 2^{\ell(n)-i} B$ (at each step of the cycle).

I conjecture that
$$
b(n) = a(n).
$$
I also conjecture that
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^n-1} c(i) =  \sum\limits_{i=0}^{2^n-1} d(i) = \prod\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} (2^j + 2).
$$
Is there a way to prove it?
